# Backbone.js - Remove standard submit event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I handle submit event of my form like so:

```
 events: {
    'submit #contactus-form': 'submit'
 },

...
 submit: function() {
   alert("handle");
 },
```

But even though I do it after seeing an alert my page refreshes and this adds to url:

```
?name=&email=&text=
```

How do I prevent standard behavior? Leaving only my handler.

Comment: u can add event.preventDefault(); wherein event is passed in submit function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are submiting the for you can use [event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent this. try this code:-

```
submit: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("handle");
},
```